# How to use dev:xml:convert?

Tags: magento2, xml, cli

I'm exploring the Magento 2 CLI and I don't know how could I apply the command below in real life?

```
bin/magento dev:xml:convert
```

Can you show me some example?

Thanks!

Comment: So, you want to make own comand,right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command is used to transform XML to XSLT. it is a way to transform the XML document into other formats such as XHTML.

Take an example

**catalog.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <catalog>
    <product>
      <name>Product 1</name>
      <status>Enabled</status>
      <price>100.80</price>
    </product>
    <product>
      <name>Product 2</name>
      <status>Enabled</status>
      <price>230.45</price>
    </product>  
  </catalog>
```

**catalogxslt.xslt**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
  <html> 
  <body>
    <h2>Product Collection</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th style="text-align:left">Name</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">Price</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="catalog/product">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="price"/></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
  </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

after this run the below command:

**bin/magento dev:xml:convert catalog.xml catalogxslt.xslt**

**Output:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <html>
        <body>
            <h2>Product Collection</h2>
            <table border="1">
                <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                    <th style="text-align:left">Name</th>
                    <th style="text-align:left">Price</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Product 1</td>
                    <td>100.80</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Product 2</td>
                    <td>230.45</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
```